# How to log calling line of code which produces an error

Tags: php

I get a notice from my php-script:

> Undefined offset: 32 in C:\xampp\htdocs\WWW\myfilexyz.php on line 74

I want to detect where the error occurs as the procedure which produces the error is called many times.

I added the following line of code:

```
error_log("you made a mistake", 3, "errorfile.log");
```

Looking into errorfile.log, the message appears 3 times, but the procedure is called more than 100 times. How can I find the 3 lines where the error is produced?

I would like to see sometime like:

> "you made a mistake, called from line 234 from start.php"

Comment: The easiest way to get a stack trace would be to convert PHP errors into exceptions, as uncaught exception [always have stack trace with it](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php)

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Or... http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest is to use a proper error handler which provides a *stacktrace* for each error. You can install [xdebug](http://xdebug.org), which outputs a lot more details about an error when activated. While you're at it, look into using xdebug to hook up a debugger (read xdebug's documentation).

Alternatively write your own [error handler](http://php.net/set_error_handler) which uses [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) to give you a decent stacktrace.

Answer (score -2):

```
$err = error_get_last();
error_log($err['message'] . ' in ' . $err['file'] . ' on line' . $err['line'], 3, "errorfile.log");
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Read the question carefully.